Uber Deep Link with 2 stops
I'm trying to create an Uber Deep Link that opens the Uber app and pre-fills the ride request with a pickup location and two stops. I've successfully created a link that works for the Uber website, but when I try to open the app, I can only include one destination. Is there a way to include multiple stops in a Deep Link that opens the Uber app?
I've tried links like this one:
https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=40.471926&pickup[longitude]=-3.562640&pickup[nickname]=Aeropuerto%20de%20Madrid-Barajas&dropoff[0][latitude]=40.416705&dropoff[0][longitude]=-3.703582&dropoff[0][nickname]=Puerta%20del%20Sol&dropoff[1][latitude]=40.413782&dropoff[1][longitude]=-3.692127&dropoff[1][nickname]=Museo%20del%20Prado&dropoff[2][latitude]=40.408511&dropoff[2][longitude]=-3.688761&dropoff[2][nickname]=Estaci%C3%B3n%20de%20Atocha
because without the indexes was working and I didn't see anything at the documentation but is not working.

Wasn't this question already asked? If it was deleted you shouldn't recreate questions.

Please share more details about how your problem is related to programming

@NicoHaase I need to create a function that redirects to the Uber app with stops, so first I need to know how to create a link to Uber.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What keeps you from creating such a function? Did you try anything to resolve the problem?

@NicoHaase I think you're not understanding the problem. How am I supposed to create a function without knowing how should be the result?
The problem is that the link to uber with stops works to open the web, but not at the app after trying a lot of ways of doing it.
I'm asking if someone has used a link with stops to Uber to knowing how the link is structured.

Feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it. If you can't even build the link, you should ask Uber's developer support for help. That's not a programming issue
